# How to put the table of contents in Arial

Tags: fonts

I have install the package for a font similar to Arial

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

However, in the table of contents the name of my sections don't show in this font but the normal latex font. I have put some subsections in my text, in one of the section, and the title of the subsections in the table of contents appear in the font similar to Arial.

Comment: Could you provide better [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem? Using the same code as you I get a working document.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a general observation: You note in the title of your question that you wish to use `Arial`, but in example code you provide you load `Helvetica`. (Arial is a "descendant", to put it politely, of Helvetica.) If you really need `Arial`, you could load the `uarial` package instead of the `helvet` package.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see the problem. Compiling this MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{The social interaction}
\subsection{Homophily}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Social distance}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

Notice that my TeXLive is regularly updated.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Is it because I include my section: \include{section} in my main document?

Comment: @Lyy: my answer is no. I've just tried to include the whole part of my code starting from `\section{The social interaction}` to `\lipsum[2]` in a file called `section.tex`. Then I used `\include{section}` after the declaration of `\chapter{Introduction}`, but it still works.